# How does Spring Kafka manual commit works in Batch listener mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a topic with 2 partitions. I am using kafka batch listener mode in my consumer application. Since, I am using a single consumer application therefore I will receive messages from both partitions. Once the consumer application process those list of messages, I want to commit the largest offset of each partition manually.

If I use MANUAL_IMMEDIATE mode, will it commit the highest offset of each partition? If not what is the approach I should use?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; `acknowledgment.ack()` will commit the offset of the highest offset of all partitions for which records were received.

However, the container will do it automatically for you if you use the default `AckMode.BATCH`. This is simpler than dealing with manual acks.