# Spring Kafka MANUAL_IMMEDIATE Acknowledge Only Commits 1 Highest Offset of 1 Partition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hello Gary and the Spring Kafka community! :)

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71382162/749337) that when using MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack mode, that it is supposed to commit the highest offset of all partitions for which records were received. This is not the behavior I am experiencing.

I am using @KafkaListener, and have an individual object and the Acknowledgement object as my 2 method parameters. I need to accumulate messages in memory, send them out after some threshold is met, and then commit all of said messages. My plan was to just commit/acknowledge the last message I receive before sending them out.

I did try keeping a Map<partitionId, Acknowledgement>, and adding to that every time. I do observe that when acknowledging every value in the map (the latest ack for each partition), it does commit all prior messages as well.

Using Spring Boot 2.7.8 w/ Spring for Apache Kafka v2.8.11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that it is supposed to commit the highest offset of all partitions for which records were received.

What makes you think that? If the documentation is misleading, I'd like to correct it.

You need to acknowledge each record (or the last one for each partition), unless your listener is a batch mode listener (receiving all the records from the poll in a `List` or the raw `ConsumerRecords`). In that case, the `Acknowledgment` is for the entire batch.

Comment: It wasn't from the documentation, it was from your stackoverflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71382162/749337

Comment: That question is about batch mode listeners; I mention the difference in my answer here.

Comment: I do see that now. Makes sense, thanks!